# entire function Res(1/f)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function and let $a_1, \dots , a_n$ be all zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that there exists real numbers $r>0$ and $t>1$ such that $|f(z)| \geq |z|^t$ for all $|z| \geq r$. Prove that

$$\sum Res(1/f,a_j)=0$$

I want to say something about the boundedness tell's us about the symmetry of the Residues but I'm unsure. Perhaps taking the Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 2):

Pick a large circle around the origin containing all the zero's. Then your sum equals to $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=R} \frac{1}{f}$  by residue theorem. Now apply ML inequality to see that the integral tends to zero as you enlarge your circle.

Comment: could you add a little more detail?

Comment: @az89 this appears to be sufficient. Try working the details on your own, first.